# Mockito - Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I have two private fields in my class which I am testing and these two fields are initialized in constructor.

Now when I am trying to call using my class annotated with @InjectMocks, it is throwing exception:

```
 Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'ServiceImpl' of type 'class com.test.ServiceImpl'. You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
```

Below is the piece of code.

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

    private OfficeDAO officeDAO;

    private DBDAO dbDAO;

    public ServiceImpl() {
        officeDAO = Client.getDaoFactory().getOfficeDAO();
        dbDAO = Client.getDaoFactory().getDBDAO();
    }
}
```

My test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceImplTest {
    
    @Mock
    private OfficeDAO officeDAO;

    @Mock
    private DBDAO dbDAO;

    @Mock
    Client client;

    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceImpl serviceImpl;

    @Mock
    private Logger log;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

Please help me how I can resolve it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No need to call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` if you declare `MockitoJUnitRunner` as junit test runner.

Comment: which version of mockito are you using

Comment: Why is the constructor name ShiftManagerServiceImpl in the ServiceImpl class?

Comment: Actually assuming that the constructor name is only a copy-paste issue, I have tried this code using Mockito version 1.9.5 with some dummy test case, but no error was experienced

Comment: I am using Mockito version - 1.9.5

Comment: Could you try instantiating via simply serviceImpl = new ServiceImpl(); after the initMocks() call instead of using @InjectMocks?

Comment: Thank you for your response, when I tried with serviceImpl = new ServiceImpl(); after the initMocks() , I am getting NullpointerException at officeDAO = Client.getDaoFactory().getOfficeDAO(); What I think Client.getDaoFactory is a static call which is coming as null in my case.

Comment: When I creating serviceImpl = new ServiceImpl(); object using new all dependents mocking are failing. Can you please tell me what's the reason behind it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `@InjectMocks` annotation, which creates an instance of `ServiceImpl` class. Because your constructor is trying to get implementation from factory: `Client.getDaoFactory().getOfficeDAO()` you have NPE.

Make sure what is returned by `Client.getDaoFactory()`. I bet it returns null and that's the problem :) Refactor your code, so that DaoFactory is passed via parameter rather than using static.

---

I see you have a different exception right now. But based on the code I cannot really tell more. Please, provide full example of failing test.

Comment: I am having another dependency which i mocked. In my test class I can see it's mocked but when control is going to service class it is coming as null.

Comment: @Test
 public void testGetOfficeForOperator() throws Exception {
  when(asignmentDao.getOfficeForOperator(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(
    serviceImplTestData.getAssignmentList());
  serviceImpl.getOfficeForOperator("ABC", new Date(), new Date());}